# Как правильно писать "молодое" заимствование сафари-драйв?

Tags: грамотная-речь, заимствования

Мне нравится дефис, но встречаются варианты и без него и почему-то с *ф* на конце...

> Кстати, в некоторые фавелы даже можно устроить сафари-драйв.

Сафари-драйв можно устроить куда-то (во что-то)?

Comment: Да чушь, конечно, где, а не куда.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дефис **нужен** - для образования сложного слова, поскольку при раздельном написании стоящее перед существительным определение должно иметь русское окончание прилагательного, а его здесь нет - заимствовано "с потрохами" (а не в виде какого-нибудь "сафарийного драйва"), как и "компакт-диск", по смыслу оригинала - "компактный".

Comment: А как насчёт *куда - во что?*

Comment: Скорее, "по просторам чего-нибудь" или пересекая пространство - это ведь не вдоль дороги в одном направлении?